# How to trigger autocomplete search event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have jQuery autocomplete setup on an input box.

It is working fine.

However, I want to have a button that when clicked will trigger autocomplete as though the user type some text in the input.  I would pass a specific string.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 8):

JQuery UI's autocomplete has a [`search`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#method-search) method:

```
myAutocomplete.autocomplete('search', 'sometext');
```

Comment: this doesn't cause the drop down options to appear

Comment: @Anthony...the docs say it should. Did you set `minLength:0`?

Comment: In the options (i.e. the object you pass when creating the autocomplete) I would assume. I think that param just means 'don't search unless the input is this long' - if you haven't set it to something, it probably defaults to 0, so that's not likely to be the issue.

Comment: @sje397 Your assumption was logical, but incorrect. minLength defaults to a value of 1, so leaving it unspecified can, indeed, cause an issue if your search string is empty.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for where `#inputID` is a text input on which the autocomplete is attached.

```
$("#inputID").autocomplete('search');
```

Tested in FireFox and Chrome (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: Huh.. I can't get this to work. I have a text input with an ID and an autocomplete created on it, which works just fine (with remote datasource, v1.9).  But if i try to do exactly the call like you mentioned (in a focus event, attached to my ID) - nothing happens. The event does happen, but the call to autocomplete('search') doesn't do anything, no drop down shows on the screen, no xHttp is made.
I have no idea what else could be missing and I'm jumping around it for hours ;(